# React Js: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError:

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I am trying to do a POST request through `fetch` in reactjs. I went through some docs but my error not solved.Can anyone please help me out?

Here is my reactjs code:

```
 handleSubmit(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var self = this;
    
       const payload = {
       id: 111,
       studentName: 'param',
       age: 24,
       emailId: 2
    };
    fetch({
       method: 'POST',
       url: 'http://localhost:8083/students',
       body: payload,
       headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
     })
       .then(function(response) {
           return response.json()
         }).then(function(body) {
           console.log(body);
         });
     }
    
  }
```

If any one familiar with reactjs, just give a simple example how to call post request.Either by using `fetch` or `axios`.

Comment: Can you please edit question, code is missing?

Comment: @niklaz Thanks for your reply, code added

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example..

```
  fetch('http://myAPiURL.io/login',{
    method:'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({
    email: userName,
    password: password
  })
  }).then(function (response) {

    //Check if response is 200(OK) 
    if(response.ok) {
      alert("welcome ");
    }
    //if not throw an error to be handled in catch block
    throw new Error(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    //Handle error
    console.log(error);
  });

for more info on how to use `fetch` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
```

Comment: In order to have a good answer, I would suggest to add more explanation to your code just to make things clearer.

Comment: @Sandeep Thanks for reply, i tried this way but same error

Answer (score 0):

Well I answered a similar question just now. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47263347/how-to-post-in-reactjs).

Well the great thing about React is that it's just Javascript.

So all you need is something to do a POST do your server!

You can use the native [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) function or a full-on library like [axios](https://www.axios.com/)

Examples using both could be:

```
// Using ES7 async/await
const post_data = { firstname: 'blabla', etc....};
const res = await fetch('localhost:3000/post_url', { method: 'POST', body: post_data });
const json = await res.json();
```

---

```
// Using normal promises
const post_data = { firstname: 'blabla', etc....};
fetch('localhost:3000/post_url', { method: 'POST', body: post_data })
.then(function (res) { return res.json(); })
.then(function (json) { console.log(json); };
```

---

```
// AXIOS example straight from their Github
axios.post('/user', {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```